# Segmenting a data frame by row based on previous rows values

Tags: r, dataframe, sas

I have a data frame in R that contains 2 columns named x and y (co-ordinates). The data frame represents a journey with each line representing the position at the next point in time.

```
      x     y seconds
1   0.0   0.0       0
2  -5.8  -8.5       1
3 -11.6 -18.2       2
4 -16.9 -30.1       3
5 -22.8 -40.8       4
6 -29.0 -51.6       5
```

I need to break the journey up into segments where each segment starts once the distance from the start of the previous segment crosses a certain threshold (e.g. 200).

I have recently switched from using SAS to R, and this is the first time I've come across anything I can do easily in SAS but can't even think of the way to approach the problem in R.

I've posted the SAS code I would use below to do the same job. It creates a new column called segment.

```
%let cutoff=200;
data segments;
set journey;
retain segment distance x_start y_start;
if _n_=1 then do;
  x_start=x;
  y_start=y;
  segment=1;
  distance=0;
end;
distance + sqrt((x-x_start)**2+(y-y_start)**2);
if distance>&cutoff then do;
  x_start=x;
  y_start=y;
  segment+1;
  distance=0;   
end;
keep x y seconds segment;
run;
```

Edit: Example output
If the cutoff were 200 then an example of required output would look something like...

```
      x     y seconds segment
1   0.0   0.0       0       1
2  40.0  30.0       1       1
3  80.0  60.0       2       1
4 120.0  90.0       3       1
5 160.0 120.0       4       2
6 120.0 150.0       5       2
7  80.0 180.0       6       2
8  40.0 210.0       7       2
9   0.0 240.0       8       3
```

Comment: Could you give us a reproducible example?  You can certainly do this with a `for` loop but it would be interesting to try to come up with a vectorized solution.

Comment: And please add how would the desired output will look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data set is `dd`, something like

```
cutoff <- 200
origin <- dd[1,c("x","y")]
cur.seg <- 1
dd$segment <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(dd)) {
   dist <- sqrt(sum((dd[i,c("x","y")]-origin)^2))
   if (dist>cutoff) {
      cur.seg <- cur.seg+1
      origin <- dd[i,c("x","y")]
   }
   dd$segment[i] <- cur.seg
}
```

should work.  There are some refinements (it might be more efficient to compute distances of the current origin to *all* rows, then use `which(dist>cutoff)[1]` to jump to the first row that goes beyond the cutoff), and it would be interesting to try to come up with a completely vectorized solution, but this should be OK.  How big is your data set?

Comment: Thanks!
I will apply this to many datasets of varying length. Some journeys last a few minutes and some several hours; all contain a row for each second. I'll try both methods and see which is more efficient.

Comment: This works perfectly quickly enough for my needs and (with the addition of a missing square root in the distance calculation!) is really clear and easy to follow.
Many thanks indeed!